# Remove rows with if conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table called Price.

It has Id(Guid),createdon(datetime),productId(guid),StartTime(datetime), EndTime(Datetime),Price(decimal)

This table can have same productId with different prices.

But I need to create a select statement with some parameters so it can always bring the correct unique price.

For example,

If there are multiple productId in that table, firstly I need to look if `getdate()` is between `starttime` and `endtime`,

If two rows have `getdate()` between `starttime` and `endtime` it should bring the `max(createdon)` row.

If starttime is not null and endtime is null, it should bring the `max(starttime)` row.

There should be always one unique productId in that table.

How can I make select statements like that.

Start Result

```
+----+------------+------------+------------+-----------+-------+
| Id | createdon  | starttime  |  Endtime   | ProductId | Price |
+----+------------+------------+------------+-----------+-------+
|  1 | 02/15/2021 | 02/17/2021 | NULL       |         1 |     2 |
|  2 | 02/16/2021 | 02/18/2021 | NULL       |         1 |     3 |
|  3 | 02/16/2021 | 02/19/2021 | 05/15/2021 |         2 |     4 |
|  4 | 02/16/2021 | 02/19/2021 | 02/25/2021 |         2 |     5 |
|  5 | 02/17/2021 | 02/25/2021 | 02/25/2021 |         1 |     5 |
+----+------------+------------+------------+-----------+-------+
```

End Result

```
+----+------------+------------+------------+-----------+-------+
| Id | createdon  | starttime  |  Endtime   | ProductId | Price |
+----+------------+------------+------------+-----------+-------+
|  2 | 02/16/2021 | 02/18/2021 | NULL       |         1 |     3 |
|  3 | 02/16/2021 | 02/19/2021 | 05/15/2021 |         2 |     4 |
+----+------------+------------+------------+-----------+-------+
```

explanation:

For ProductId=1

- Id 1,2,5 have productId=1 but
- Id 5 endTime is ended so 1 and 2 remained, 2 max starttime is closer to `getdate()`
- So row 2 must be in the selected.

For ProductId=2

- Id 3 endtime is bigger than `getdate()`
- Id 4 endtime is ended
- So row 3 must be in the selected.

BTW productId and Id are guid, I wrote as int in the example for easier read.

Comment: please show your attempt, some sample data and the expected result. For your requirement, please have a look at `ROW_NUMBER()`

Comment: Start over. You shouldn't need to do that AT ALL. You should constrain your table such that a product can have only one price for a given time period. Because you lack this, you push the associated work into EVERY query that needs to find the "correct price" for a given date. And I find the use of datetime rather than date very suspicious - but perhaps your pricing is more variable than most.

Comment: I added data examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` to identify the price that you need.

The `WHERE` clause filtered the valid price. `order by StartTime` in `row_number()` is to get the latest `StartTime`. `isnull(EndTime, '99991231')` is to handle cases where `EndTime` is `NULL`

```
select *
from
(
    select *,
           rn = row_number() over (partition by productId 
                                       order by StartTime desc,
                                                EndTime desc,
                                                CreatedOn desc)
    from   Price
    where  StartTime      <= convert(date, getdate())
    and    (
                EndTime   >= convert(date, getdate())
           or   Endtime   is null
           )
) p
where  p.rn = 1
```

[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e18873aee74f97da6ed764024e8ab71e)

Comment: Thank you for that fast reply :) You are amazing bro. I have tested it It works, But If there are valid EndTime like 2022 and NULL row, It brings the NULL row. It should bring the valid one.

Comment: change `isnull(EndTime, '99991231')` to `EndTime`. Updated the query

Comment: I changed but the result is same, 1 row starttime 2019 and endtime 2022 productId=1 other row starttime 2019 endtime NULL productId =1 , it brings the endtime NULL one. You have updated I m trying.

Comment: EndTime desc -- Null >2022 i guess

Comment: change to `order by StartTime desc, EndTime desc, CreatedOn desc`

Comment: also updated `dbfiddle` with additional sample data `starttime 2019 and endtime 2022...` case

Comment: in this example it works otherwise https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=11262b4d4a7f8def6726b9398239ec11

Comment: `ID 6` has later start time `2019-02-20` so the `rn` is `1`. Basically you can change the `ORDER BY` expression to your requirement accordingly. It will determine the `rn` value of the rows. You may verify that by removing the `WHERE p.rn = 1`

Comment: can we put an if condition before that order by ? It will look first if it has valid enddate, if a row has a valid enddate takes it, if not, that orderby works. because as you can see table has some inconsistent data and changing order by might break other datas aswell. looking with if conditions can fix it.

Comment: you can use `CASE` expression to do that. `order by case when EndTime is not null then 1 else 2 end, StartTime desc, EndTime desc, CreatedOn desc`